# How can i check how many requests are not being handled (PHP Nginx)

Tags: php, nginx

We have a web service that is php on nginx.
Is there a way that i check how many of the requests are not being handled?
(Do not get processed by php and therefore do not get a reply to the request)

Comment: What did you mean by `requests are being unhandled`? Request which was not accepted or request which are now in processing?

Answer (score 0):

You may need a combination of Nginx and PHP status and log files.

Nginx status: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpStubStatusModule

PHP status: http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php

Comment: Please explain what exactly i need to check there. Thanks!